# Unable to open iterator for alias -Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to load an XML file using XMLLoader(Piggybank) in Pig, but I get an error saying "unable to open iterator for alias B". 
I have written the following code:

```
REGISTER /home/hdfs/spig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar
A = LOAD '/core-site.xml'using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('property') as (x:chararray);
B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<property>\\s*<name>(.*)  </name>\\s*<value>(.*)</value>\\s*<description>(.*)</description>\\s*</property>'));
dump B;
```

The following is the log file:

### Pig Stack Trace

> ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias A
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable
>   to open iterator for alias A  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:935)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)     at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:631)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:927)     ... 13 more

Comment: Can you post the full error please?

Comment: @PradeepGollakota I have added the log file.

Comment: I tried to dump A , and in response I got the above error as shown in the log.

Comment: Not sure if the answer here is sufficient yet, but perhaps this helps: [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like one of your jobs might have failed.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
```